# Does Xcode 4 have any affect on the current version of MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

Is it safe to install Xcode 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today's release of MonoTouch will let you install XCode 4 and continue building applications with MonoTouch.

But if you use install XCode 4, you wont be able to edit your XIB files.   We advise developers to install the new XCode 3 release that contains support for iOS 4.3 and still comes with Interface Builder.

We are hard at work at building a new integration system from MonoDevelop to XCode4 (since they now merged Interface Builder with XCode)

Answer (score 0):

updated release is out - it fixes the problems I had earlier

http://monotouch.net/News/post/New-MonoTouch-releases-for-iOS-43.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From what the folks in IRC have said: XCode 4 is not yet supported, so don't install it.