# Creating outlets in Xcode4

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, xcode3to4

I recently upgraded to xcode4 and now I cant create outlets at all. The only documentation that I can find says to use drag and drop feature to connect my outlets, which is useless to me as I'm developing in monotouch.

How can I create outlets in interface builder like I could in Xcode3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look a the answer of Miguel de Icaza [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265375/does-xcode-4-have-any-affect-on-the-current-version-of-monotouch).

Interface builder isn't supported in Xcode4 in the current release of MonoTouch.

Comment: Damn, I was hoping the new release ment it was ready... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of:
[Monotouch and XCode 4, where did the outlets go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636088/monotouch-and-xcode-4-where-did-the-outlets-go)

I had the exact same problem. I contacted the excellent crew over at monotouch by mail, and within short time they sorted it out. It turned out i could keep the SDK upgrade but I had to downgrade to the 3.x version of xcode. Hopefully there will be an update soon that will allow us to use the latest xcode incarnation - although I personally hope monotouch get's it's own GUI designer.